# Inner Join in my SQL

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

My attempt is to return the information of those people who have emails with "is_read=0":

```
 SELECT 
        a.*, b.*,c.*, COUNT(a.EmailNum) as NumEmails
    FROM 
        Emails.emails a
    inner join 
        Employees.user b on a.ID=b.id 
    inner join 
        Employees.dept c on b.dept=c.deptid
    where 
        a.is_read='0'and c.deptName='HR';
    group by 
        b.id
```

Emails.
   emails(Table):

```
   emailNum, id, emailcontent,receivers
   1       , 11, "sasa"      ,sa@gmail.com
```

Employees:

```
   user(Table)
   userId, firstName, lastName, dept
   1`    , 'John'   ,  'Brown', 55
```

Employees:

```
       dept(Table)
   deptId, deptName
   55    , 'HR'
```

My attempt gives:

```
  emailNum, id  ,  emailcontent, receivers,   userId, firstName, lastName, dept, deptId, deptName
   null   , null,  null        ,  null    ,    null ,    null  ,  null   , null  ,  55  , 'HR'
```

But I expect it does not return anything!

Thanks

Comment: Try aliasing your tables with letters that at least imply their identities.  `u` for `users`, `d` for `depts`, for example.  It makes it easier to understand the relationships that are relevant in the query.

Comment: BTW I dont know why Im getting lots of negative score:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `;` between your `WHERE` clause and your `GROUP BY`:

```
where 
    a.is_read='0'and c.deptName='HR';
group by
```

This is splitting your query into two... the first part runs without the `GROUP BY`, the second part gives you an error.

When the query runs without the `GROUP BY` you get a row with `NULL` values instead of an empty result set because of the aggregate function.

Remove the `;`, and you should get the expected results.

[SQL Fiddle with the `;`.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1678/2)

[SQL Fiddle without the `;`.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1678/4)

Answer (score -1):

Try this, Inner joins generally are nested within one another

```
SELECT 
    a.*
   ,b.*
   ,c.*
   ,COUNT(a.EmailNum) as NumEmails

FROM 
   Emails.emails a
       inner join Employees.user b 

            inner join Employees.dept c 
            on b.dept=c.deptid

       on a.ID=b.id 

WHERE 
   a.is_read='0'
   and c.deptName='HR';
group by 
   b.id
```

( Also, try grouping by a.*, b.*, c.* )

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but this isn't valid SQL... inner joins aren't nested like this.

Comment: I downvoted, because inner joins are not generally nested like this.